# Take list elements as strings in new lines on html page using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, html

I have one list of bugs = ['bug1','bug2']. I want to put that in HTML page which I create from python script.

```
bgs = "print '\\n'.join(bugs_list)"

html_str = """
<html>
<body>
%(bugs_list)s
</body>
</html>
"""% {'bugs_list' : bgs}
```

How can I take bgs value as strings in new lines on html page?

```
bug1
bug2
```

bgs = exec(bgs) -> I can't take output of exec in variable, so got stuck here. Can someone please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: The first line should be `bgs = '<br>'.join(bugs_list)`

Comment: Why do you want to `exec` that string? Just join with `<br>` and put that string into the HTML.

Comment: That dint work, it prints "print '<br>'.join(bugs_list)" in html file.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there any particular reason why you want to create the HTML "by hand" rather than using any of the existing template engines?

Comment: @UnholySheep, It was just one small html page for experiment, so dint go for template engines.